# StructureMap can't register open generics with default convention properly

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am trying to register all my open generic types with default convention.
If I use default convention like below I can confirm that my type is registered correctly.

However when I try to resolve it it throws following error.

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IGenericClass'

```
 public DefaultRegistry()
        {
            Scan(
                scan =>
                {
                    scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                        a => a.FullName.StartsWith("StructureMapApp"));
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });
        }

var container = new Container(x =>
    {
        x.AddRegistry(new DefaultRegistry());

    });
    container.WhatDoIHave();

    var result = container.GetInstance<IGenericClass<DummyClass>>();
```

Here is the container.WhatDoIHave() result
container.WhatDoIHave()[image]

If I register it by explicitly it works as expected.

```
       container.Configure(x => x.For(typeof(IGenericClass<>)).Use(typeof(GenericClass<>)));
        var sad = container.GetInstance<IGenericClass<DummyClass>>();
```

Here is container.WhatDoIHave() result

[image]

As you may notice there is a slight difference between two registries.The registry made with default convention includes assembly and model name while explicit one doesn't have.

[image]

Is there any way Auto register all open generics without explicitly provide all of them ?

Comment: What is DefaultRegistry?

Comment: Forgot to add it,I added it

Comment: As far as I know - default convention is not intended to do that, you need to write custom regitration convention.

Comment: I suppose there is not any pre built in convention for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `DefaultConvention` doesn't do that. But you can create custom convention, for example:

```
class MapOpenGenericTypesToInterfacesConvention : IRegistrationConvention {
    public void ScanTypes(TypeSet types, Registry registry) {
        var openInterfaces = types.FindTypes(TypeClassification.Open | TypeClassification.Interfaces).ToArray();
        var openConcrete = types.FindTypes(TypeClassification.Open | TypeClassification.Concretes);
        foreach (var type in openConcrete) {
            foreach (var iface in openInterfaces) {
                if (type.GetInterfaces().Where(c => c.IsGenericType).Any(ti => ti.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == iface)) { 
                    registry.For(iface).Use(type);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add it with

```
scan.With(new MapOpenGenericTypesToInterfacesConvention());
```